# Text input with options such as Bulleted list

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im looking to create an input field on a web application that is similar to the one we use here for posting questions, where you can put list items, make font bold/italic etc

Does anybody know here know of the code to do this? or could they point me in the right direction of code snippets/hints...ive tried using google chromes 'inspect element' function but cannot find the actual code behind it except that they have a class and id

The languages I can work with are JavaScript, HTML, CSS, VBScript. Ideally I wouldnt want to abstract from these languages at this time if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Exchange uses [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), a WYSIWYM (What you see is what you mean) markup language. The original implementation is in Perl, although ports to many other server-side languages are also available.

The editor you're looking at is a [modified version](https://github.com/derobins/wmd) of [wmd](http://wmd-editor.com/), combined with [showdown.js](https://github.com/derobins/wmd/blob/master/showdown.js), a JavaScript implementation of the original Markdown language that allows client-side rendering of Markdown text into HTML which allows you to see the preview when writing and editing posts here.

Comment: wow thank you :) such a quick response. I am looking at wmd now. I shall come back should this solution not work :) if it does work I will mark this as the solution :)